# How to prevent scrolls Up after rows are inserted on TableView

Tags: uitableview, core-data

Currently, I've a Pull Down To load more old messages on my TableView. The issue is that after new messages get append to tableview it scrolls up. What I would like to do is to maintain the same scrollPosition after new messages are loaded on the Tableview.

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this by saving the current offset before the new messages are appended, and scrolling (back) to that offset after the messages were added.

If you're using an `NSFetchedResultsController`, you could handle this in `controllerWillChangeContent:` and `controllerDidChangeContent:`.

*You will have to defer your scrolling, or disable animation from the insert (or scrollToRow), since the table can't smoothly animate back up to the previous offset, in the midst of animating down due to the inserted rows.*